# Why does editing leaves behind the previous mesh?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

[image]

I don't know what exactly to ask for but every time I try to edit this mesh, it leaves behind the old mesh; occasionally with a connection to the edit. Please help. I can't find a way around this issue.

[image]

Comment: You have another copy of your mesh in your scene.

Answer (score 3):

There is a active Mirror Modifier on your Object. However the mirrored Object is not a half Object but a full Object already. You can see this also by the mirrored vertex transformations on the other leg. So either cut your mesh in half and still use the mirror modifier, or delete the mirror modifier

Comment: Holy heck that makes sense. Thanks, my guy!